# Compare contents of HashSet against a map

Tags: java, java-8, hashset

I have a Map and a HashSet.
The goal is to check the contents of the Set against the Map and add it to the Map if the elements are there in the HashSet but not in the Map.

```
// Map is defined in a class 
private final Map<String, A> sb = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void someMethod() {
    Set<A> hSet = new HashSet<>();
    for (A a : ab){
        hSet.add(a..a...);

        // Check if all elements added to hash Set are there in a Map 
        // if not present, add it to Map 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output? It's not clear from your code what you're trying to do. What is the `String` key?

Comment: You no longer need to check `.containsKey` or `.contains` as answerers are suggesting -- in Java 8 you can use `map.putIfAbsent(k, v)`

Comment: Is not clear what you want to do, but you should be able to do something like `ab.forEach(a -> sb.putIfAbsent(key, a));`

Comment: Under what key would you put an `A` into the map?

Comment: @StephenP since this is a `ConcurrentHashMap`, it always supported the `putIfAbsent` method. In fact, you *must* use it instead of pre-checking via `containsKey`, if the update is supposed to be thread safe.

Comment: Thanks @Holger I had never looked into that

Comment: "sb" isn't a good name for a map, and you refer to it in the code as "ab". I suggest changing both to a better name, such as "map".

Answer (score 2):

if you want to search in map values:

```
if(!map.values().contains(a))
   // put a in the map
```

if you want to look for keys

```
if(!map.containsKey(a))
  // put a in the map
```

keep in mind that contains calls equals so in your A class you have to implement hashCode and equals.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> set = Stream.of("a","b","c","d").collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("a", "foo");
    map.put("h", "bar");
    map.put("c", "ipsum");

    for (String string : set) {
        if(!map.containsKey(string)) {
            map.put(string,string);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

output

```
{a=foo, b=b, c=ipsum, d=d, h=bar}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String element : hSet) {
    if (!sb.containsKey(element)) {
        sb.put(element, A);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following could also be solution:

```
private final Map<String, A> sb = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void someMethod() {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.stream().filter(word -> !sb.containsKey(word))
                .forEach(word -> sb.put(word, correspondingValueOfTypeA));
    }
```